# Boxplot and line with dual y-axis from two data frame using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using ggplot to put boxplot and line in the same plot. I have two data frames, here are snippets for these two DFs:

```
 TMA.core variable    value
1      I-5      H&E 356642.6
2      B-1      H&E 490276.9
3      B-13      H&E 460831.8
4      L-11      H&E 551614.2
5      B-6      H&E 663711.8
6      F-10      H&E 596832.8
```

(there are many variables.)

```
    TMA.core     Mean        CoV
   I-5 390829.7 0.15181577
   B-1 414909.9 0.21738852
   B-13 500829.8 0.39049256
   L-11 537229.7 0.07387486
   B-6 575698.9 0.44764127
   F-10 589245.2 0.15382864
```

What I want to do is draw boxplot using the first data frame and then plot the CoV for the corresponding TMA core and connect using geom_line.
My codes are:

```
ggplot() +
geom_boxplot(data = Merge_stats_melt, aes(x = reorder(TMA.core, value, FUN = mean), y = value)) + 
geom_line(data = Merge_stas_mean_order, aes(x = reorder(TMA.core, Mean), y = CoV, group = 1)) + 
scale_y_continuous(
# Add a second axis and specify its features
sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1000000, name = 'CoV')
)
```

Using these codes I can draw the boxplot but the line is always a horizontal line at y = 0.
How to solve this issue?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot a combined bar and line plot in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002397/how-to-plot-a-combined-bar-and-line-plot-in-ggplot2)

Comment: This answer is still using one data frame, but I am using two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using one or two data frames doesn't really matter. Just remember to adjust the y aesthetic accordingly, which you forgot to do.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
```

Find the ideal scaling factor for the dual axis

```
ratio <- max(Merge_stats_melt$value) / max(Merge_stas_mean_order$CoV)

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = Merge_stats_melt, aes(x = reorder(TMA.core, value, FUN = mean), y = value)) + 
  geom_line(data = Merge_stas_mean_order, aes(x = reorder(TMA.core, Mean), y = CoV*ratio, group = 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=comma,
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./ratio, name = 'CoV')
  )
```

---

[image]